# Como desativar o botão "Ver detalhes" na pré-visualização da imagem?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-3

Estou utilizando: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

Aqui está um exemplo em jsfidde : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30000/

Como desativar esse botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="input-id" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
```

**JS:**

```
$("#input-id").fileinput({ showRemove: true, showUpload: false, showCaption: true, showZoom: true, zoomIcon: false });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diretamente pelo plugin eu não consegui remover, consegui utilizando css:

```
.file-footer-buttons {
    display: none;
}
```

Somente deixei de exibir a div que contém os botões na parte inferior.

Answer (score 2):

Adicione as opções:
`{'fileActionSettings':{'showZoom': false}`

```
$("#input-id").fileinput({
     fileActionSettings: {
         showZoom: false
     },
     showRemove: true,
     showUpload: false,
     showCaption: true,
     showZoom: true,
     zoomIcon: false
});
```

Comment: Ele perde controle `fileActionSettings:{showZoom: false}` após de atualizar página.

Comment: Recomendo então utilizar a solução do amigo @Denis.
Porém, dessa forma.

    .kv-file-zoom {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Só desativar não faz sentido uma vez que irá passar a ideia que não esta funcionando como deveria.. ou seja "bugado" o que pode ser feito é utilizando um display:none no CSS marcando-o como !important porque certamente vai ler de acordo ao link do css..

```
.krajee-default .file-footer-buttons {
float: right;
display: none;
```

}